# Uniform convergence on compact sets of a sequence of convex functions taking values in $\mathbb R \cup\{+\infty\}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, convex-analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $X:= \mathbb R^n, Y:= \mathbb R \cup\{+\infty\}$, and $(u_k)$ with $u_k:X \to Y$ be a sequence of convex functions such that $u_k$ converges pointwise to $u:X \to Y$. The *effective domain* of $u$ is defined as $\operatorname{dom} u := \{x\in X \mid u(x) \in \mathbb R\}$. Assume that $\operatorname{int} (\operatorname{dom} u) \neq \emptyset$.

Then the author of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261690/pointwise-convergence-for-a-sequence-of-convex-functions-implies-uniform-converg?rq=1) post said that

> - I **have proved** that, for every compact subset $K$ of $\operatorname{dom} u$, the sequence $(u_k)$ is equi-bounded and equi-Lipschitz on $K$.
> - I want to prove that $(u_k)$ converges uniformly on every compact subset of the effective domain of $u$.

---

First, we fix

- a compact subset $K$ of $\operatorname{dom} u$,
- a point $a \in K$,
- and $N \in \mathbb N^*$.

Assume $u_k(a) = +\infty$ for all $k \le N$. Then the sequence $(u_k)$ can not be equi-bounded and not equi-Lipschitz on $K$. However, the pointwise limit of $(u_k (a))_{k \in \mathbb N}$ is not effected by those $u_k$'s with $k \le N$. So I suspect the author's claim is not correct?

> Could you please confirm if my understanding is correct?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: I added another counterexample to those question. Could you please check?

Comment: @daw I could not see anything wrong with your example. It may be worth noticing that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $(-\infty, 1-\varepsilon]$ for any $\varepsilon >0$. Could you post your counter-example as an answer so that I can accept it?